# Simple NAND logic gate question

Tags: logic

Is

```
a ----|
       --- NAND ---|
b ____|            |
                   |
                   ---- NAND --- 
c ----|            |
       --- NAND ---|
d ____|
```

the same as

```
a ----|
       ------|
b ____|      |
             |
             ---- NAND --- 
c ----|      |
       ------|
d ____|
```

?

How would you write the expression for the first one and second one?

Comment: What gate in the second one: AND, OR, NOR, XOR, or something else for the unlisted section?

Comment: the second one, is 4 input into a nand gate.

Comment: Could you write truth tables for each to see if the answers are the same?

Comment: I never thought of that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't be the same. The first one would be written as ((ab)'(cd)')'. The second one is (abcd)'. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the second gate means $NAND(A,B,C,D) = \neg (A \land B \land C \land D)$

Ok, that is not the same as the first gate, since e.g. if A and C are true but B and D are false, then $NAND(A,B,C,D)$ is true (since they are not all true), but for the first gate, both 'middle' NAND gates will output true (since not both inputs are true), and hence the final NAND gate will output false (since both its inputs are true).